# Nested mapping only for test create NullPointerException Junit 5

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mapping

Class by class I explain why it doesn't start, thanks for your help

In debug i see the list of employees until the method for-each

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.fincons.mapper.EmployeeMapper.mapEmployeeToEmployeeDtoWithoutObjects(com.fincons.entity.Employee)" because "this.employeeMapper" is null

at com.fincons.mapper.DepartmentMapper.lambda$mapDepartmentToDepartmentDto$0(DepartmentMapper.java:26)
```

The other test where i don't use this mapper works.

TEST CLASS

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {DepartmentServiceTest.TestConfig.class})
public class DepartmentServiceTest {


    static class TestConfig {

    }
    @InjectMocks
    private DepartmentServiceImpl departmentService;
    @Mock
    private DepartmentRepository departmentRepository;
    @Spy
    private DepartmentMapper departmentMapper;
    @Spy
    private EmployeeMapper employeeMapper;


    @BeforeEach
    void init() {
        departmentRepository = mock(DepartmentRepository.class);

        // Initialize the service with mocks
        departmentService = new DepartmentServiceImpl(departmentRepository, departmentMapper, employeeMapper);
    }
```

```
@Test
void testGetDepartmentByIdExist() {

    // Configures the behavior of the mock for repository
    long departmentId = 3L;
    Department existingDepartment = new Department(3L, "name", "address", "city");
    Position position = new Position(3L, "Web Developer", 1500.0);

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.parse("1942-03-10", formatter);
    LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.parse("1942-03-10", formatter);
    LocalDate date3 = LocalDate.parse("1942-03-10", formatter);
    Employee employee = new Employee(5L, "Carlo", "Verdone", "carlo.verdone@gmail.com" , "Male", date1, date2, date3 , existingDepartment, position);
    List<Employee> newListEmployee = new ArrayList<>();
    newListEmployee.add(employee);
    existingDepartment.setEmployees(newListEmployee);



    when(departmentRepository.findById(departmentId)).thenReturn(existingDepartment);

    ResponseEntity<Object> response = departmentService.getDepartmentById(departmentId); //NULLPOINT

    assertTrue(response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful());
}
```

SERVICE

```
@Autowired
private DepartmentRepository departmentRepository;

@Autowired
private DepartmentMapper departmentMapper;

@Autowired
private EmployeeMapper employeeMapper;


@Autowired
public DepartmentServiceImpl(DepartmentRepository departmentRepository, DepartmentMapper departmentMapper, EmployeeMapper employeeMapper) {
    this.departmentRepository = departmentRepository;
    this.departmentMapper = departmentMapper;
    this.employeeMapper = employeeMapper;
}

@Override
public ResponseEntity<Object> getDepartmentById(long id) {

    Department existingDepartment = validateDepartmentById(id);
    DepartmentDTO departmentDTO = departmentMapper.mapDepartmentToDepartmentDto(existingDepartment);

    return ResponseHandler.generateResponse(LocalDateTime.now(),
            "Success: Found department with ID " + id + ".",
            (HttpStatus.OK),
            departmentDTO);
}
```

FIRST MAPPER: where i have null point exception when i launch the for-each.
in particular lambda$mapDepartmentToDepartmentDto$0

```
public DepartmentDTO mapDepartmentToDepartmentDto(Department department) {
    if (department.getEmployees() != null) {
        List<EmployeeDTO> employeeDTOList = new ArrayList<>();

        department.getEmployees().forEach(employee ->
                employeeDTOList.add(employeeMapper.mapEmployeeToEmployeeDtoWithoutObjects(employee))
        );
        return new DepartmentDTO(
                department.getId(),
                department.getName(),
                department.getAddress(),
                department.getCity(),
                employeeDTOList);
```

It's as if you couldn't create the EmployeeMapper constructor

SECOND MAPPER

```
public EmployeeDTO mapEmployeeToEmployeeDtoWithoutObjects(Employee employee){
    return new EmployeeDTO(
            employee.getId(),
            employee.getFirstName(),
            employee.getLastName(),
            employee.getGender(),
            employee.getEmail(),
            employee.getBirthDate(),
            employee.getStartDate(),
            employee.getEndDate());
}
```

I need to resolve the NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
@Spy
private DepartmentMapper departmentMapper;
@Spy
private EmployeeMapper employeeMapper;
```

Use this one approach:

```
private final DepartmentMapper departmentMapper= 
Mappers.getMapper(DepartmentMapper.class);


private final EmployeeMapper employeeMapper = 
Mappers.getMapper(EmployeeMapper.class);
```

A very good article and explanation about how `spy` work you have to check [mockito-spy](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-spy).

By the way, why not to use `spring-boot-starter-test` annotations and work with them ?